# Parsing Json with linked hashmap java using JsonPath

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have some json that contains a linked hashmap I can get the element I want using gson like this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create()

JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(message.getBody(), JsonObject.class)
JsonElement entry=job.getAsJsonObject("MessageAttributes").getAsJsonObject("eventId").get("Value")
```

I want to use JsonPath something like this

```
JsonObject j = JsonPath.read(awsBody, "$['MessageAttributes']")
j.getAsJsonObject("eventId").get("Value")
```

although this gives me the error `No such instance method: 'com.google.gson.JsonObject java.util.LinkedHashMap.getAsJsonObject (java.lang.String)'`

Here is my json

```
{
    "MessageId": "8342fb55-9db8-42cb-8f59-c6abc8039b72",
    "Type": "Notification",
    "Timestamp": "2020-04-15T14:40:06.927960Z",
    "Message": "Some message here ",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:quote-event",
    "MessageAttributes": {
        "eventId": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "HELLO-WORLDaaa-4bb04d9e-2522-4918-98c9-5a88094d3a3a"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `value` key it would be:

`$['MessageAttributes']['eventId']['Value']` or `$.MessageAttributes.eventId.Value`

For testing and experimentation use [this site](https://jsonpath.com/). Also, use [this one](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html) to read jsonPath's specification.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

1. JsonPath doesn't work with GSON object directly as it uses `net.minidev.json` library internally so `JsonPath` needs to be configured first
2. `[]` is used for indexes, range or condition-based selection so to access the `MessageAttributes` object, use `$.MessageAttributes` path.

Create a configuration object for `GSON` as

```
Configuration config = Configuration
    .builder()
    .jsonProvider(new GsonJsonProvider())
    .mappingProvider(new GsonMappingProvider())
    .build();
```

Now use the configuration while reading the object as:

```
JsonObject j = JsonPath.using(config).parse(awsBody)
        .read("$.MessageAttributes"); // path for MessageAttributes, is an elemnt from root

String value = j.getAsJsonObject("eventId").get("Value");
```